# ng-pageslider when using ps-container

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've implemented the [ng-pageslide directive](https://github.com/dpiccone/ng-pageslide) in my project. It works great in Chrome when I allow its default behavior and allow it to attach to the body tag. However, it causes layout issues in Firefox for a page that uses [UI Bootstrap tabs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs). It basically shifts everything to the right.

The styles that ng-pageslide adds to the body tag are:

```
position: absolute; transition-duration: 0.5s; transition-property: top, bottom, left, right; right: 0px;
```

I've tried removing these manually when transition to a page that doesn't use pageslide, but that seems like a bad solution.

I've also tried using the ps-container attribute and structuring my HTML like this:

```
<div id="tasks">
    <!-- table using ng-repeat -->
    <pageslide ps-open="project.sidebar" ps-auto-close="true" ps-squeeze="true" ps-body-class="true" ps-container="tasks">
</div>
```

This HTML template is included by a ui-tabset using:

```
<uib-tabset justified="true">
    <uib-tab ng-repeat="tab in project.tabs" active="tab.active" select="$state.go(tab.route)" disable="tab.disabled">
        <uib-tab-heading>
            <i class="fa fa-{{tab.icon}}"></i>
            <span translate="{{tab.titleKey}}">{{tab.title}}</span>
        </uib-tab-heading>
        <div ng-include="tab.content" class="m-t-sm"></div>
    </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

When I use this setup, I experience two issues:

1. The table is initially squished to the right side of the page.
2. When I open the page slider, it slides over 300px from the right and ends up covering my table, instead of squeezing it.
3. The panel that slides out seems to cut off its contents. I've noticed I can fix this by adding `style="height: 100%"` to the "tasks" element.

Screenshots:

[image: table squished to right]
[image: pageslide positioning with ps-container]

What do I need to do to make ps-container work like adding pageslide to the body tag?